# DataGridTextColumn to display description selected by code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

At code behind, I have list of code with their descriptions fetched from a database. 
eg: {(code1, Description 1), (code2, Description 2)}

i'm storing this as `Dictionary<string, string> StatusText` in my code behind.

the data source for the page is an xml file viz loaded into `XmlFile` and set as the data context for the page. `Reports` is a member of `XmlFile` and is an array which is the source for the data grid.

The 'Status' column of datagrid is bound to `Reports.StatusCode`. I need to use `StatusCode` to look up the value from `StatusText` and display the value part in the 'Status' column.

Now that i need to display the corresponding description for the code value in the DataGrid, i'm almost lost. the datagrid has to be non-editable, hence i prefer DataGridTextColumn or similar for the column type.

I'm comparatively new to wpf.

XAML

```
<Page x:Class="Project1.ApprovalQueue"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="ApprovalQueue" Loaded="Page_Loaded"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <uc:TextToVisiblityConvertor x:Key="TextToVisiblity" />
</Page.Resources>
<Page.DataContext>
    <h:XmlFile x:Name="XmlData" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid Name="GrdData" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <DataGrid Name="DGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            CanUserSortColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" IsReadOnly="True"         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionChanged="DGrid_SelectionChanged"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Reports, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DueStatus" Width="16">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <!--  ReSharper disable Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved - This will be generated at Runtime  -->
                            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=ImgOverDue, Path=Source}" Height="16" Width="16" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextToVisiblity}, Path=OverDue}"/>
                            <!--  ReSharper restore Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved  -->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="IncompleteStatus" Width="16">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <!--  ReSharper disable Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved - This will be generated at Runtime  -->
                            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=ImgIncomplete, Path=Source}" Height="16" Width="16" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextToVisiblity}, Path=InComplete}"/>
                            <!--  ReSharper restore Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved  -->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptStatus" Width="100" Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Path=StatusCode}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptDesc" Header="Report Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptState" Width="150" Header="Current State" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="RptDate" Width="100" Header="Submit Date" Binding="{Binding Path=SubmitDate}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

The code behind

```
public partial class ApprovalQueue
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> StatusText = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public ApprovalQueue()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = MyConnection.GetLookupData("GetTrans", "report_status", int.MinValue);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            StatusText.Add(Convert.ToString(row[0]), Convert.ToString(row[1]));
        }
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\XForms\APPQREFRESH.XML");
        ProcessAppQueue(ref fileInfo);
    }

    private void ProcessAppQueue(ref FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (XmlFile));
        var reader = new StreamReader(fileInfo.FullName);
        XmlData = (XmlFile) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
        DGrid.ItemsSource = XmlData.Reports;
        Debug.WriteLine("here");
    }        

    private void DGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //DataRow dRow = 
        //TxtDesc.Text = Convert.ToString(dSet.Tables["REPORT"].Rows[grid.CurrentRowIndex]["DESC"]);
    }
}
```

the data source

```
namespace Helper
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("XML_FILE")]
    public class XmlFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Report[] _reports;

        [XmlArray("REPORTS")]
        [XmlArrayItem("REPORT", typeof (Report))]
        public Report[] Reports
        {
            get { return _reports; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _reports)
                {
                    _reports = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Reports Changed");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Report : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _reportType;

        [XmlAttribute("TYPE")]
        public string ReportType
        {
            get { return _reportType; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _reportType)
                {
                    _reportType = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("ReportType");
                }
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("FILE")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("S_DT")]
        public string SubmitDate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("STAT")]
        public string StatusCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("OVER")]
        public string OverDue { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("INCM")]
        public string InComplete { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DESC")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some of your code so others might get a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: If anyone here is going to be able to provide you with example solution code, we'll need to know the names and type of your properties. Please show us your classes.

Comment: what issue you are facing. please put some code..

Comment: add code as recommended. the issue point is at 'RptStatus' in the datagrid. my (Key, Value) pair is 'StatusText'. I need the value of this to appear at 'RptStatus' based on the value of 'Report.StatusCode' as you may see, my grid Source is 'Reports'

Comment: You have to simplify your question, there are so many confusing codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your problem is that you're trying to display something that does not exist in the collection that is data bound to your `DataGrid`. The answer is simple... add it into the collection. This is one way that you could do this *before* you set it as the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`:

```
foreach (Report report in Reports)
{
    report.StatusCode = StatusText[report.StatusCode];
}
```

This will replace the codes in the `StatusCode` property with the description. If you don't want to replace that value, then you could just add an extra column into your `Report` class:

```
public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Sheridan, I finished off that by adding an extra column. Why I was searching for a "pick-from-list" kind of solution was because i needed the same logic for more columns.

Comment: Though I understand binding is powerful, it's way too complex to get good grasp on the concept if you are migrating from earlier mechanisms.

Comment: While I do understand your sentiment from your last comment, I would disagree about the complexity of data `Binding`... you can find out all you need to know from the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. Furthermore, learning about `Binding` will help you so much in future WPF applications.